# How can I capture screen (in video format) in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg

I want to capture the screen (or all the actions done in a canvas). I require this in video format and do not want a screenshot but a video of all actions done on the screen over a period of time.

I want to implement this functionality in HTML5.

Please advise. Also if this is not possible in HTML5, please suggest alternative technology for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding right, you want to save a canvas with an interval of x ms. That part's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf).

Note that you 're not clear in your question. Do you want to capture the screen, the complete document or a single canvas?

Second part do you want to render it as a 'video like' component using javascript? Or do you want to save it as a video. The first idea [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448555/rendering-a-chain-of-images-like-a-video-in-javascript). De second one not so much. At least not using javascript. You could send all images to a backend (like php, asp, jsp) and create a video on the server side using tools like ffmpeg. [More info](https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-convert-video-to-images)

Comment: Capturing is easy. The interesting part is compressing the captured video.

Comment: indeed...certainly if it's going to be used by lots of people simultaneously compressing will, take time and require quit a lot of resources.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I know webworkers are for running the heavy stuff in the background (sort of like threading). But I don't see any possible solution of capturing/compressing video on the client side using javaScript...

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 doesn't offer camera capabilities.
But, there's a [jQuery Plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) that offers just that using a small flash utility..